# Redux - how to save input value despite reRender?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Redux - how to save input value despite reRender?
Now it can put value, save change, BUT only 1 point data ago
So when I click 2-nd - will get 1-st

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fields = {}
}
....
onChangeName(e) {
    this.fields.tableName_input = e.target.value
}
onChangeParticipants(e) {
    this.fields.tableParticipants_select = e.target.value
}
componentDidUpdate(params){
    if (params.editing){
        console.log(params)
        let tableName_input = this.fields.tableName_input && this.fields.tableName_input || params.table.name
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.tableName_input).value = tableName_input
        let tableParticipants_select = this.fields.tableParticipants_select && this.fields.tableParticipants_select || params.table.participants
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.tableParticipants_select).value = tableParticipants_select
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no redux related code in your question.

Comment: The problem was in Redux dispatch - when Editing reducer was called with params.editing = true, but all other call default case, but that parameter was still true. I thought that problem in my React code in the Component, written above

Answer (score 0):

Please add the code that fires the saving, I think the problem it's in how you update the fields parameter.

But, doing this as a property is not good, you should keep the fields values as a state, if you're managing through redux, I would recommend you to take a look to [redux-form](http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/), this library is pretty awesome, and lets you manage the form fields into the redux state, which is useful for testing and keep your components pure, the content will be in the redux state.